# How can the options set on a Spark DataFrameReader be viewed?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

The `Spark` `DataFrameReader` has an `options()` method: but it is a *setter*: ie it is used to impose options on the *Reader*

```
        datasource_options = {'driver': 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver', 
                              'timestampFormat': 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'}
        df_reader = (
            self.spark.read.option("kustoCluster", self.data_source.cluster)
            .option("kustoDatabase", self.data_source.database)
            .option("kustoQuery", resource.query)
            .options(**datasource_options)
        )
```

I would like to confirm the options that have been set into the `Reader` but have not found a method to do so. Does it exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't exist as part of the public api, it's a [private field](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8f1b02880cb9b82af39bb624e7fcab00b880fd4c/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala#L774) in a [private class](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8f1b02880cb9b82af39bb624e7fcab00b880fd4c/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala#L57).

The content is additionally interpreted differently for different datasources, it's not something you should attempt to workaround either (although doable) as it's possible to change between versions.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this but it not the best solution :

```py
datasource_options = {'driver': 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver', 
                      'timestampFormat': 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'}
df_reader_options = {
    "kustoCluster": self.data_source.cluster,
    "kustoDatabase": self.data_source.database,
    "kustoQuery": resource.query
}
df_reader_options.update(datasource_options)

df_reader = self.spark.read
for key, value in df_reader_options.items():
    df_reader = df_reader.option(key, value)
```

Comment: I guess the question was somewhat unclear: I wanted to print out the options.