# Show the options set on a Spark DataFrame Reader

Tags: apache-spark

We have set a number of options via a combination of `spark.read.option(optName, optVal)` and `spark.read.options(dictOfOptions)`.  How can the values that have been set be read back from the `DataFrameReader` instance?  The API does not show anything  [Spark DataFrame Reader API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can the options set on a Spark DataFrameReader be viewed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77212767/how-can-the-options-set-on-a-spark-dataframereader-be-viewed)

Comment: oh yea that's my own question, just forgot, will close

Comment: :) I actually tried to just flag it as a duplicate - I knew it was yours, wouldn't have bothered if this was the outcome of flagging. ah well

Comment: i could not delete because there's already an answer. i'll just wait for it to get closed (i added my vote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options are kept in private field `extraOptions` and by looking into code I don't see there is a way of reading it.

Comment: thx for looking